# type object 'DocxTemplate' has no attribute 'tables'

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I can acess the atrribute tables in my first doc. But when I go to the second doc2 I can't acess the atrribute tables.

How can I fixxed this?

This is my code and results

```
    from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, InlineImage

    doc = DocxTemplate("document1.docx");
    doc2 = DocxTemplate('document2.docx'); 

    In[26]: doc.tables
    Out[26]: 
    [<docx.table.Table at 0x2859ed41910>,
    <docx.table.Table at 0x2859ed41640>,
    ....]
 
    In [27]: doc2.tables
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11456\862834077.py", line 1, in <module>
    doc2.tables

    File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\template.py", line 59, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.docx, name)

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tables'
```

Comment: This means `doc2` is `None`. Something went wrong creating the second doc. Was there any error message when you ran the line initializing doc2? What do you see when you just print doc2?

Comment: Hi Joanis, Has no error when I ran the line initialization doc2. When I print doc2 I get: <docxtpl.template.DocxTemplate object at 0x000001D09B67C190>

When I print doc I get: <docxtpl.template.DocxTemplate object at 0x000001D09A68B9A0>.

doc works, but doc2 doesn't work when I tried to use the attributes "table".

Comment: I discovered one solution. If I receive my docx in python code with "doc2.save('filename.docx)" the attribute tables works. I don't know why this happened hehe

Comment: ...If I **save my docx in...